# How do I make my project depend on other projects via msbuild?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I only have the names/locations of my other projects but I dont want to require the developer to add project dependencies himself.
So my prebuild event needs to add "references" (=anything that makes the current project depend on the other one) via some kind of msbuild magic.
Is that possible?

Desired pseudo code:

```
<Task Name="MyOwnPrebuild">
   <AddProjectDependencies ItemGroup="@MyProjectPaths" />
</Task>
```

Where I would fill the @MyProjectPaths array by iteratating over my windows folders recursively in some other task before calling this one.

Comment: That's not possible.  Standard chicken-and-egg, by the time MSBuild decides to start running the pre-build event, it has already figured out the dependencies.  Trying to change them again doesn't work.  Don't hide dependencies, the client programmer doesn't stand a chance to figure out what is wrong when it blows up.

Comment: "by the time MSBuild decides to start running the pre-build event, it has already figured out the dependencies" well at least from looking at the CoreBuild in Common.CurrentVersion.targets it shouldnt be true what you are saying, the ResolveReferences; is right after the PreBuildEvent.

Comment: The order or targets in the .targets file is not relevant.  You can easily reason this out yourself, MSBuild does *not* actually build anything if it isn't necessary.  Which of course requires it to know if dependencies have changed before it starts to do anything, including running the pre-build event.

Comment: well okay, but then the BeforeBuild should suffice. CoreBuild was just a suggestion. Here the text on DependsOnTargets seems to strongly suggest that the execution order is the same as the declaration order. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee216359.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my specific case there is (luckily!) a stupidly simple, yet beautiful answer:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="..\**\*.csproj">
     <Private>false</Private>
   </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

This includes all my projects from all(?) subfolders! Exactly what I want in this particular case. If I want to restrict to a specific type of project, I could easily use a more specific regex.

Comment: Warning for others: Somehow Visual Studio seems to try to be "smart" and expand this for me. Doesn't seem to happen on every build, so I have to watch this.